# Different size of log-bin files in master-master Mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, multi-master-replication

I have master-master Mysql replication. Each master replicates other master. Could anyone please explain me why log-bin files on that master are different? (The difference in size is quite small).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. We've decided to use mysql 5.6 and its feature - GTIDs. It's resolved our problem.